# Conceptualising the switch from discrete molecules to the continuum (fluid dynamics)

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I understand that $\rho(x,t)$ represents the density of the small volume surrounding  the point $x$. However what have I done with the discrete molecules in the process of averaging?

Comment: You may want to look up the Chapman-Enskog theory because it is what provides the bridge from the Boltzmann equation to the Navier-Stokes equations (ie. molecular->continuum). The wikipedia page is, unfortunately, very lacking on it though.

Answer (score 0):

They key here is to go from a 'sufficiently dense ensemble of particles' to a continuous theory. But to outline here all the calculations involved would be tedious.

Therefore I explain the concepts briefly.
A nice reference is [Fitzpatrick's plasma course](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/lectures1/node27.html) and [this course](http://theory.physics.helsinki.fi/~xfiles/plasma_jatko/10/asp2010/ASP10_Ch3.pdf) which explains how we take the average to go from a multi-particle distribution function $N(\vec x,\vec p, t) = \sum_i \delta(\vec x - \vec x_i(t)) \cdot \delta(\vec p - \vec p_i(t))$ to the first continous distribution function $f(\vec x, \vec p,t)$.
In the latter formalism we want to get rid of the momentum space, and approximate $f$ as multiple moments $\int dv f\cdot v^n$.
This works well if $f$ is a gaussian, then we have the $\int dv f\cdot v^0  =\int dv f=\rho$, also $\int dv f v=\vec v$ and $\int dv f\cdot v^2 = E_{kin}$.

Ok, that was very short, tell me if you need more help.

Comment: I've only just been introduced to this continuum hypothesis.I just want to understand it conceptually at a basic level. What am I averaging? Am I taking the average value of the density at each point in the small volume surrounding the point x  or am I taking the average density of each molecule in the small volume.